# Search, Sort with AJAX

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, search, sorting, jquery

I've reproduced the code from RailsCasts episode [240](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax). I have no idea why with this code the Ajax requests don't work. The search function works with the normal method (reload page) sadly not through Ajax. The sort function works not at all.

I've included following JavaScript libraries:

- application.js
- jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.2
- jQuery UI 1.8.15
- jQuery.rails.js
- jQuery TinySort v1.1.0

If you need more information please let me know. I hope really you can help me to solve the problems.

**users_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @users = User.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
  end
end

def sort_column
  User.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "lastname"
end

def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>

<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get', :id => "users_search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
  <div id="users">
    <%= render 'users' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_users.html.erb**

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
<table class="pretty">
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable "Last name" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "First name" %></th>
  </tr>
  <% for user in @users %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= user.lastname %></td>
      <td><%= user.firstname %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$("#users").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("users")) %>");
```

**users_helper.rb**

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
end
```

**application.js**

```
$(function() {
  $("#users th a").live("click", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
  $("#users_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#users_search").attr("action"), $("#users_search").serialize(), null,     "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the above code to work, you have to **delete** the following lines of code.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
end
```

Now it works. :-)